# How can I assign a std::string from a char *

Tags: c++

This may be trivial, but I'm new to `C++` and an getting confused here.

I have the method:

```
bool load_database_file( const std::string& filename, std::string& contents ) {

    std::ifstream is (filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (is) {
        // get length of file:
        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = (int)is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);

        char * buffer = new char [length];

        std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
        // read data as a block:
        is.read (buffer, length);

        if (is)
            std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
        else
            std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
        is.close();

        // ...buffer contains the entire file...

        std::string str(buffer);
        contents = str;

        delete[] buffer;
    }

    return true ;  
}
```

where I would like to read a file and assign it's contents to `contents` so that it can be read by the calling function.

My issue is that after this function is run, I see that only the first character of `buffer` was copied to `contents`.

How can I copy/convert the entire contents of `buffer` (a `char *`) to `contents` (a `std::string`).

Comment: Did you get the example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/)? Please note that in this case your length is one too short to hold a zero-terminated string, and second that you don't zero-terminate your string before assigning it to `std::string`.

Comment: What encoding is the file using?

Comment: @MicroVirus I got the example from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Comment: Then my remark holds true. David Schwartz's answer circumvents the issue.

Comment: `char * buffer = new char [length];`  Replace that with this:  `std::vector<char> buffer(length);`

Answer (score 2):

```
    std::string str(buffer);
```

Should be:

```
    std::string str(buffer, buffer+length);
```

Otherwise, how can the constructor know how many bytes to allocate/copy?

By the way, your code is needlessly clumsy. Why not read directly into the string's buffer rather than using a separate buffer that you have to allocate and free just to hold the data before you allocate another buffer?

Comment: Because before C++11 there was no guarantee of contiguity in `std::string`? And, actually, because the OP _should_ be reading in a loop, to ensure he has all the characters. You don't know how many `read` invocations that'll take. A buffer inside a loop is the conventional way to handle that.